# Is there a difference in meaning when I move the word “not”?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, difference, british-english

Compare

> I do not want to be lonely

with

> I want to not be lonely

and

> I want to be not lonely

I feel like there’s a difference here - the first is saying the speaker doesn’t want to *become* lonely and the latter two are saying the speaker wants to stop being lonely.

Im also not convinced by the grammaticality of the last two.

Am I right - if so, is there a name for this change in meaning by moving this one word, or is it just a quirk if English?

Answer (score 1):

While the first sentence looks good, I don't think the second version of the sentence is grammatically correct: "not be" cannot just hang there in an infinitive form, not in this case. For instance, in "Can I not be lonely?" the infinitive being there is alright, since it is one of the modal verbs.

The third sentence, to me, isn't necessarily grammatically incorrect, but asking for improvement by replacing "not lonely" with a synonym that doesn't contain negation. Another way for to make it sound good in its initial above form is to complete it, as in, "I want to be not lonely but (adj.)".

Also, I do agree that the first sentence is saying that the speaker doesn’t want to become lonely and the latter is saying that the speaker is already lonely and wants to stop being that.

Lastly, I'm not sure about a name of this procedure, if there is any.